# Net::SMTPFatalError in rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm getting the following error when trying to send email on rails 2.3.4(it worked on 2.3.2) using action_mailer_tls plugin:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError in UsersController#create

555 5.5.2 Syntax error. w3sm66205164ybi.9


C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:930:in `check_response'
C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:899:in `getok'
C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:828:in `mailfrom'
C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:653:in `send_message'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:683:in `perform_delivery_smtp'
C:/Program Files (x86)/NetBeans 6.8/ruby2/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:526:in `start'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:681:in `perform_delivery_smtp'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:523:in `deliver!'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:395:in `method_missing'
D:/Proyectos/Cursometro/www/app/models/user_observer.rb:3:in `after_create'
D:/Proyectos/Cursometro/www/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:221:in `create_new_user'
D:/Proyectos/Cursometro/www/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:101:in `create'
```

This has happened after I changed the following line at action_mailer(smtp_tls.rb file):

```
 #check_auth_args user, secret, authtype if user or secret
    check_auth_args user, secret if user or secret # Ruby 1.8.7 FIX
```

Comment: you forgot to add a line of action_mailer.

Comment: You're right. I edited the original post. There is the line. Anyway, I think I have a conflict between my gems environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was happening due to a conflict between my gems environments. I adjusted some things and now it's solved.